Who can manage SharePoint term store?
I've got term store like department.
What is the permission level required to manage this term store?

To manage SharePoint term store, you must have one of three specific roles: term store admin, group manager, or contributor. These roles are assigned specific tasks that they can perform in the term store. A term store admin can create or delete term set groups, add or remove group managers or contributors, change the working languages for the term store, and perform any task that a group manager or contributor can do. A group manager can add or remove contributors and perform any task that a contributor can do. A contributor can create or change a term set. Therefore, to manage a term store, you must have at least one of these roles assigned to you.
Reference: Assign roles and permissions to manage term sets.
